# C++ - Problema con generar una función void 'menú'

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de generar un método en el cuál el usuario presionando un número pueda realizar una acción (En este caso sería pasar de Verdadero a Falso la supuesta poliza de un cliente). Sin embargo cuándo lo invoco en el menú me la consola me señala el error.

> error: 'polizaEnMemoria' was not declared in this scope|

Entonces me pregunto ¿Tengo que pasar por parámetro el vector? Si tienen algún material adicional estaría muy agradecido. Los códigos.

El procedimiento menú:

```
char menu(void)
{
    char opcion;
    cout <<"Polizas en memoria.\n\nSelecciones una opcion: "<< endl;
    cout <<"1 - Cargar una nueva poliza" << endl;
    cout <<"2 - Desactivar una poliza existente" << endl;
    cout <<"3 - Buscar por numero de poliza" << endl;
    cout <<"4 - Buscar por numero de DNI" << endl;
    cout <<"5 - Listar polizas activas ordenadas por incidentes descendetemente" << endl;
    cout <<"6 - Procesar incidentes" << endl;
    cout <<"7 - Sobreescribir archivo y salir" << endl;
    cout <<"8 - Crear incidente" << endl;
    cout <<"Esc - Salir" << endl;

    do
        opcion = getch();
    while ( (opcion < 49 || opcion > 57) && opcion != 27 );

    switch(opcion)
    {
        case '1':
            cout << 1;
            break;
        case '2':
            desactivarPoliza(polizaEnMemoria,TAMANO);
            break;
        case '3':
            cout << 3;
            break;
        case '4':
            cout << 4;
            break;
        case '5':
            cout << 5;
            break;
        case '6':
            cout << 6;
            break;
        case '7':
            cout << 7;
            break;
        case '8':
            cout << 8;
        break;
    }
    return opcion;
}
```

El main desde donde invoco el procedimiento menú:

```
int main()
{
    poliza polizaEnMemoria[TAMANO];
    levantarAsegurados(polizaEnMemoria, TAMANO);
    char opcion;
    do
        opcion = menu();
    while(opcion != 27);
    return 0;
}
```

El procedimiento desactivar poliza

```
void desactivarPoliza ( poliza V[],int tam)
{
    int i = 0;
    int PolizaADesactivar;
    cout << "Ingrese numero de poliza que desea desactivar" << endl;
    cin >> PolizaADesactivar;
    bool encontrado = false;
    while (i < tam && V[i].nroPoliza!=999999)
        {
            if (V[i].nroPoliza == PolizaADesactivar)
                {
                    if (V[i].polizaActiva == 'f')
                    {
                        cout << "La poliza ya se encontraba desactivada" << endl;
                        getch();
                    }
                    if (V[i].polizaActiva == 'F')
                    {
                        cout << "La poliza ya se encontraba desactivada" << endl;
                        getch();
                    }
                    V[i].polizaActiva  = 'F';
                    encontrado = true;
                    cout << "La poliza se desactivo correctamente" << endl;
                    getch();
                }
            i++;
        }
    if (encontrado == false)
       {
          cout << "No existe esa poliza" << endl;
          getch();
          return;
       }
}
```

Una última pregunta más general que tengo es ¿Es preferible crear un procedimiento menú o codificarlo en el main?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo con este fragmento de código:

```
int main()
{
    poliza polizaEnMemoria[TAMANO];
    levantarAsegurados(polizaEnMemoria, TAMANO);
    char opcion;
    do
        opcion = menu();
    while(opcion != 27);
    return 0;
}
```

`polizaEnMemoria` es una variable local que existe únicamente en `main`. Sin embargo en la función `menu` estás haciendo lo siguiente:

```
char menu(void)
{
    // ...    

    switch(opcion)
    {
        case '1':
            cout << 1;
            break;
        case '2':
            desactivarPoliza(polizaEnMemoria,TAMANO);
            //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

En esta última función no existe ninguna variable que se llame `polizaEnMemoria` y de ahí las quejas del compilador.

Solucionar el error es tan sencillo como pasarle el array a la función `menu()`:

```
char menu(poliza* polizaEnMemoria)
{
  // ...
}

int main()
{
   // ...

   opcion = menu(polizaEnMemoria);
}
```

> ¿Es preferible crear un procedimiento menú o codificarlo en el main?

Siempre es preferible dividir el programa en porciones lógicas pequeñas y manejables. Sus beneficios son inmensos frente a un escaso número de *peros*.

**algunas ventanas**

- Código más versátil. Se puede cambiar el comportamiento del programa con muy pocos cambios
- Código testable. Al estar organizado el programa con funciones sencillas, el comportamiento de las mismas puede validarse mediante baterías de test.
- Mejora la escalabilidad. Añadir nueva funcionalidad es mucho más sencillo ya que buena parte del trabajo suele consistir en crear funciones nuevas en vez de tener que recurrir a modificar la mitad del código del programa.

**inconvenientes**

- El código puede ser mínimamente más lento: Es un efecto normal. Si en un programa introduces una función el compilador tiene que programar un salto en el código (haciendo los backups de los registros del procesador que considere oportunos). Como norma general este impacto es mínimo y muy pocas veces justifica evitar el uso de funciones.

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias! - Una última duda: ¿Qué significa el asterisco en: poliza* polizaEnMemoria?

Comment: @jqc es un puntero. Mi consejo es que consigas un curso o libro de C++ y te lo estudies con ganas... si flaqueas en la base vas a sudar tinta con este lenguaje.